# Why is my npm run dev command not working?

Tags: reactjs, npm, crud, mern, refinejs

I am building a new project using refine and react. I have downloaded all of the files and dependences using `npm` but when I try to open them by using `npm run dev` I get an error.

My files:
[image: My files if they help]

I'm trying to do the project in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4lHXIzCEkM&t=80s) and when I type `npm run dev` I get this error:

> > refine-project@0.1.0 dev
> > refine dev
>
> 'Crud' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file. internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905   throw err;
> ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module
> 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop@refinedev\cli\dist\cli.js'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
> at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "refine-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.2",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.3",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.85",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.6",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.6.0",
    "@refinedev/cli": "^2.7.4",
    "@refinedev/core": "^4.28.2",
    "@refinedev/inferencer": "^4.3.2",
    "@refinedev/kbar": "^1.1.2",
    "@refinedev/mui": "^5.0.0",
    "@refinedev/react-hook-form": "^4.1.2",
    "@refinedev/react-router-v6": "^4.1.0",
    "@refinedev/simple-rest": "^4.0.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.41.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "core-util-is": "^1.0.3",
    "i18next": "^20.1.0",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.1",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "^3.2.2",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.30.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.8.11",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.16.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.57.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.57.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "vite": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "refine dev",
    "build": "tsc && refine build",
    "preview": "refine start",
    "refine": "refine",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "refine": {
    "projectId": "SUjkIB-RDWgKs-moVUlK"
  }
}
```

I have started my project from 'refine.new' - I don't know if that helps?

This is what I have tried:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
npm i core-util-is
npm i -f    
npm cache clean --force
npm config set ignore-scripts false
```

Comment: The pic is my files By the way

Answer (score 1):

The error "'Crud' is not recognized as an internal or external command," means that your code is trying to run "Crud" as a command, but it can't find it.

I suggest comparing your code with the tutorial's [Client](https://github.com/refinedev/refine/tree/next/examples/mern-dashboard-client) or [Server](https://github.com/refinedev/refine/tree/next/examples/mern-dashboard-server) repo to find any differences. And try using CTRL + SHIFT + F to search for "Crud" in your code and see if it shows up.